# ¿Cómo pasar datos categóricos de un archivo .json a númericos con pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

verán tengo una base de datos de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero pasar a datos númericos el género, instrumento, nota, instumento, etc. (Esas serían mis columnas), este es mi código:

```
from __future__ import print_function 
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
#from tensorflow import tensorflow_data_validation as tfdv


#-------Preproceso de datos---------------
partituras = pd.read_json('./base.json')
df_nota =pd.get_dummies(partituras, columns=["nota"])
print (df_nota)
```

El problema es que no me reconoce las columnas del archivo, y python me tira el siguiente error:

KeyError: "None of [Index(['nota'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Este es un fragmento de mi archivo (no lo subo todo porque tiene 347 datos y la página se me traba cuando lo intento subir completo):

```
"__collections__": {
       "MisCanciones": {
        "dato1": {
        "genero": "R&B",
        "instrumento": "piano",
        "valorcompas": "3/4",
        "metronomo": 120,
        "duracioncancion": 60,
        "numerocancion": "1",
        "nota": "do",
        "escala": 4,
        "alteracion": "ninguno",
        "posicion": 1,
        "figura": "blanca",
        "numerocompas": 1,
        "efecto": "puntillo",
        "clave": "fa",
        "__collections__": {}
      },  
        "dato2": {
        "genero": "R&B",
        "instrumento": "piano",
        "valorcompas": "3/4",
        "metronomo": 120,
        "duracioncancion": 60,
        "numerocancion": "1",
        "nota": "mi",
        "escala": 5,
        "alteracion": "ninguno",
        "posicion": 1,
        "figura": "corchea",
        "numerocompas": 1,
        "efecto": "tresillo",
         "clave": "sol",


        "__collections__": {}
      },  
        "dato3": {
        "genero": "R&B",
        "instrumento": "piano",
        "valorcompas": "3/4",
        "metronomo": 120,
        "duracioncancion": 60,
        "numerocancion": "1",
        "nota": "si",
        "escala": 4,
        "alteracion": "ninguno",
        "posicion": 1,
        "figura": "corchea",
        "numerocompas": 1,
        "efecto": "tresillo",
        "clave": "sol",

        "__collections__": {}
      },  
        "dato4": {
        "genero": "R&B",
        "instrumento": "piano",
        "valorcompas": "3/4",
        "metronomo": 120,
        "duracioncancion": 60,
        "numerocancion": "1",
        "nota": "sol",
        "escala": 4,
        "alteracion": "ninguno",
        "posicion": 1,
        "figura": "corchea",
        "numerocompas": 1,
        "efecto": "tresillo",
        "clave": "sol",       

        "__collections__": {}
      },  
        "dato5": {
        "genero": "R&B",
        "instrumento": "piano",
        "valorcompas": "3/4",
        "metronomo": 120,
        "duracioncancion": 60,
        "numerocancion": "1",
        "nota": "mi",
        "escala": 5,
        "alteracion": "ninguno",
        "posicion": 2,
        "figura": "corchea",
        "numerocompas": 1,  
        "efecto": "tresillo",
        "clave": "sol",
        "__collections__": {}
      },  
        "dato347": {
        "genero": "R&B",
        "instrumento": "piano",
        "valorcompas": "3/4",
        "metronomo": 120,
        "duracioncancion": 60,
        "numerocancion": "1",
        "nota": "si",
        "escala": 3,
        "alteracion": "ninguno",
        "posicion": 3,
        "figura": "corchea",
        "numerocompas": 41,
        "efecto": "tresillo",
        "clave": "fa",

        "__collections__": {}
      }

       }

 }
}
```

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo?

Comment: Por favor agrega el json completo como texto (en vez de imagen), para que podemos evaluarlo mas facil. Clic [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/304386/edit) para editar la pregunta.

Comment: Listo! solo que solo agregué un fragmento, ya que es muy largo y se me trababa la página si lo intentaba subir todo.

Answer (score 0):

Asumiendo que el parseo del json se hace correctamente, posees un DataFrame que posee los campos como columnas y los elementos como filas.

Como existen columnas numéricas que pueden ser tomadas como string. Para hacer la transformación se hace de la siguiente manera:}

```
columnas_numericas = ['metronomo', 'escala'] # por ejemplo queremos transformar estas dos de String a 'int32'
for column_name in columnas_numericas:
    df[column_name] = df[column_name].astype('int32')  # puede ser un tipo de python str/int/float o de numpy.dtype como 'int32'/'float32'
```

Debo notar que aparentemente el json que colocaste no posee la estructura serializada de una tabla, que debería ser una lista de diccionarios con los mismos campos. En tu caso es un diccionario el cual sus llaves del primer nivel corresponden a los elementos de la lista, segun entiendo. Por lo que deberías fijarte que el método parse_json esté entregandote un DataFrame en el formato de tabla con sus columnas, y entonces esta solucion te resultará directamente.